# Fall-back color with multiple backgrounds css background property

Tags: css, background, fallback

When I use the `background` property like this, it works fine:

```css
#my-element {
  background: #000000 url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/m-main-background.webp") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;
  color: #ff00ee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="my-element">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euis
tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use multiple images, none of the images load unless I take out the fall-back color:

```css
#my-element {
  background: url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/m-main-background.webp") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed, #000000 url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/main-background.jpg") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;
  color: #ff00ee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="my-element">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euis
    tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl 
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this:

```css
#my-element {
  background: url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/m-main-background.webp") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed, url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/main-background.jpg") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;
  color: #ff00ee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="my-element">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euis
    tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl 
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this is? Is that just the way it is or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are trying to set `background` twice...in the same declaration. if you want multiple background images *those* can be comma separated but not backgrounds

Comment: So why doesn't it work to just set ```#000000``` once at the beginning followed by two urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with Sam_'s help, I figured out that you can only have `background-color` specified on the second image, like this:

```css
#my-element {
  background: url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/m-main-background.webp") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed, #000000 url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/main-background.jpg") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;
  color: #ff00ee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="my-element">
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euis
    tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl 
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks Sam!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Remove the fallback background colour and specify it separately.

```
background: url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/m-main-background.webp") left 
bottom/cover no-repeat fixed, url("https://www.airstarkennels.com/images/main- 
background.jpg") left bottom/cover no-repeat fixed;


/*Falls back to this*/
background-color: #000000;
```

Comment: I tried that but what I was using the fallback color for was so the background would be black while my background image was loading. It looks like the default color is ```rgb(0, 0, 0)``` anyway though.

Comment: Sam, in your original post you were right to put the property `background-color` **after** `background`. Any missing value from the background shorthand properties will be reinitialized so `background-color: #000000;` is not used in your current code.

Comment: Yes, I think your right. Is that working for you @claronic?

Comment: Yes, that works but do you have any idea why setting ```#000000``` once followed by two images doesn't work?

Comment: I think what is happening is that you are setting the background colour to #00000, then once the first image is loaded that is loaded over the top, Then since you are setting another fallback colour to #000000 it then colours it in again.

Comment: @Sam_ Check out my second code snippet. I removed the second color property and it still doesn't load either image or the color. In the inspector, it says it's an invalid property name and doesn't even try to load it.

Comment: I'm struggling too. I've found an article which could be some use to you - https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/background-css-shorthand/

Comment: You may be better off simply stating each property separately. I tried including the fallback colour in different locations but no luck.

Comment: @Sam_ According to that, only the second property can have a color specified. Let me try changing my second snippet.

Comment: It worked like it was supposed to. If I gave it to invalid urls, it displayed the ```#000000``` for the background